# Storing different types of "messages" in a simple chat application

Tags: sql

I have a simple message system: User sends a message to the group.

I'm trying to normalise as much as possible and do things correctly so the schema can evolve if/when needed.

I decided to have a table that stores every message, and a 2 tables for the different types of messages.

But I've found a problem with this. The queries to `message` are meaningless as they don't produce a message. You have to query `message_image` and `message_text` individually. Which makes me think that my model is wrong.

```
message
-------
+ id (int)
+ group_id (int)
+ sender_id (int)
+ created_at (timestamp)

message_image
-------------
+ id (int)
+ title (varchar)
+ url (varchar)
+ created_at (timestamp)

message_text
------------
+ id (int)
+ message (varchar)
+ created_at (timestamp)
```

Are there any negatives to doing this?

Comment: Will you have more than one image per message, and/or more than one message per image?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter just one image per message. And one text message per message. It can be one or the other, not both.

Comment: So can you add a foreign key constraint to `message` that references `message_image` as well as a foreign key constraint that in `message` that references `message_text`?  Then you can look for rows in `message` where those cols <> NULL, if you really want to separate text and image in different tables

Comment: @EatPeanutButter the alternative being a single `message` table that has a message and contains an optional image? I'm just thinking what if in the future videos were to be added. It makes it more difficult. I think I'll add the FK constraint seems like the logical way to go. Put as answer.

Comment: Perhaps http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better forum for such questions, as currently written, it is off topic for SO. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @dubes I disagree, this type of question is fine for SO. OP had a specific question about DB model design; why would that be off topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a foreign key constraint to `message` that references `message_image` as well as a foreign key constraint that in `message` that references `message_text`. Then you can look for rows in message where those cols <> NULL.